# Como copiar arquivos em rede usando C++

Tags: c++, arquivo

Estou tentando copiar um arquivo de um servidor para a minha máquina, simplesmente o código executa, não me retorna nenhum erro, porém não copia o arquivo.

Segue o código C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 CopyFile("\\\\server\\Teste\\arquivo.pdf","\\\\MeuPc\\c$\\arquivo.pdf",true);
}
```